# Optimizing function to find maximum

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have a function I would like to maximize the excess return depending on the weights that are assigned to the inputs. The inputs are not typical weights for the holdings but rather weights to assign to specific input data. Then the input data are accumulated based on the weights assigned to them to create a new variable. The top 3 holdings are selected and then the excess return of those 3 holdings is determined over the benchmark. My goal is to maximize the excess return of the 3 holdings by having the perfect combination of weights for the input data. In essence, I want to know what combination of input variables creates the highest expected return.

Below is the code for what I have so far. Unfortunately when I run the scipy.optimize.minimize, it doesn't end up changing the weights at all. I start them at 0.5 for each input variable and they stay at 0.5 by the end.

```
weights = np.array([0.5]*len(maindata.columns))

def ret(weights):

    spyreturn = pd.Series()
    portfolioreturn = pd.Series()

    maindata = pd.DataFrame(maindata*weights).sum(axis=1)
    holdings = maindata.sort_values(ascending=False)[:longamount]

    returns = pd.read_csv('Pulls in the daily return data for the stocks from computer')
    returns = returns.set_index('Date')

    spyreturns = pd.read_csv('Pulls in the daily return data for the benchmark from computer')
    spyreturns = spyreturns.set_index('Date')

    long['weight'] = 1/len(long)

    longreturns = returns[long.index]

    longreturns.replace(np.NaN,0,inplace=True)
    weightlong = longreturns*(1/len(long))

    longportfolio = weightlong.sum(axis=1)

    totalportfolio = longportfolio
    totalportfolio = totalportfolio[1:]
    portfolioreturn = portfolioreturn.append(totalportfolio)
    spyreturns = spyreturns[1:]
    spyreturn = spyreturn.append(spyreturns)

    portfolioreturn1 = portfolioreturn+1
    portfolioreturncum = portfolioreturn1.cumprod()-1
    del spyreturn[0]
    spyreturns1 = spyreturn+1
    spyreturnscum = spyreturns1.cumprod()-1

    excessreturn = float(portfolioreturncum[-1:])-float(pd.Series(spyreturnscum[-1:]))
    excessreturn = excessreturn*-1
    return excessreturn

from scipy.optimize import fmin_ncg, fmin
results = fmin_ncg(ret,weights)
```

Below is the maindata:

```
ticker,column0,column1,column2,column3,column4                                                       
IQ112350,  4.003915,       NaN,       NaN,  0.730028,  3.740035   
IQ121729, -1.812199,  0.080070, -1.044188, -1.367218, -1.560262   
IQ126269,  1.579733, -0.073775,  0.384691,  0.605217,  1.197185   
IQ128209,  0.640059,       NaN,       NaN,  0.347553,       NaN   
IQ140283, -1.569323, -0.168380, -1.269472, -0.044812,       NaN   
IQ19691,   0.263715,  0.126087,  0.371266,  0.386789,  0.498745   
IQ21127,   0.264036,  1.394952,  0.875616,       NaN,  0.180892   
IQ21171,  -0.059215,  0.128939,  0.844162,  2.702458,       NaN   
IQ21835,   1.184896,  1.439033,  0.727373,  0.701876,  0.999958   
IQ22247,   0.371498,  0.482316,  0.446124,  0.432492,  2.579207
```

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Note - I do not have to use Scipy for this. If there is a better suggestion on how the achieve what I am looking for that would be great. I have started looking into Monte Carlo Methods to complete the objective.